# Convert Joomla 2.5 template to 3.0

Tags: templates, joomla3.0

I have a custom joomla 2.5 template and I wish to convert it to Joomla 3.0. Currently the only method I found is how to convert a Joomla 1.5 to 2.5. Please guide me here because I have spent almost a month on this. I found a method http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Converting_A_Previous_Joomla!_Version_Template but I do not understand how to go about it. If you could also give a clear procedure on how to implement the steps in the link I have posted this would help me alot.

Comment: Please post the code for the index.php in your template and we can convert it for you. If you need to hide sensitive code then do that first. That will be much easier. But if you enable debug mode then you should be able to see any errors and then fix them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be in a detail manner but here you go with some steps:

1. Identify plain HTML from Joomla 2.5 template. Keep it in separate
   file for a moment.
2. There are many functions, constants that are deprecated in Joomla
   3.x e.g. DS constant which is used to provide "/" in Joomla 2.5. You need to replace it with "/".
3. Common functions like getting sitename, logo etc. will need a code
   change. You can take a reference from Protostar template. You can
   see how they have retrieved value of sitename from the code. It
   seems to be hard at first but when you go ahead gradually, you will
   get familiar with Joomla 3 template engine.
4. Once everything is done, you can go ahead and edit XML file. You can copy and paste templateDetails.xml from Protostar template. Make sure to change important elements like filename, folder etc.

Zip the whole template folder and install it on your website make it default. If you find any errors then go ahead and turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) in PHP. Resolve those errors and make your template work on Joomla 3

Answer (score 0):

This is not the absolute guide I can offer you, but here are the basic steps:

- it really depends if it's a basic template or if it's based on a template framework like RocketTheme or YOOtheme
- check the default template in Joomla, it's called Protostar. Have a close look at it and understand what is he doing
- check you manifest file (compare it to Protostar)
- maybe not so important, but check also the [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3.0 and Joomla Platform 12.1](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#CMS)
- if you have issues at installing the template / using it, please post specific problems

Comment: When I try installing the template I get this error.

Warning

JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\xampp\htdocs\upgrade\tmp\install_516fdddd9d220\images\trans.gif

What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, the error is quite explicit. trans.gif is missing. Check your template file to see if inside your template you have `images\trans.gif`

Comment: I was able to get around that by installing via the Directory. Though I am still getting errors when i set the template as the default.

Comment: I finally got the template to install with no erros, but the problem i have now is that the module positions do not work, the only thing loading is the logo, up to this line of code <strong class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $tpl->base_url(); ?>"><?php echo $tpl->sitename(); ?></a></strong> in index.php. I am certain that the issue is in index.php, I want to know if I should re-define all the module positions. How are the module positions defined in Joomla 3.0, everything in the manifest file seems inorder.