# Upgrade Joomla template 2.5 to 3.4.8

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I'm new to CMS Joomla. For a school project, me and my 'team' have to upgrade an already existing website to the newest Joomla version, which is 3.4.8. We have already managed to upgrade the Joomla version itself to 3.4.8, but the problem we came across now is the template the website is using (2.5 template). Our teacher said we cannot change the template, so we will need to upgrade it. We have been looking for an answer, but we are not able to find one. Can you help us?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess if the template is available for joomla 3 then there won't be any issue. Else you need to create your own template or use in-bulit joomla 3 template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Joomla 2.5 template to 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055707/convert-joomla-2-5-template-to-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article -
[Template Considerations During Migration](https://docs.joomla.org/Template_Considerations_During_Migration)

And these 3 are the best links for upgrading template

## 2.5 to 3 Template Conversions

1. [J3.x:Converting A Previous Joomla! Version
   Template](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J3.x:Converting_A_Previous_Joomla!_Version_Template)
2. [Convert Joomla 2.5 template to 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055707/convert-joomla-2-5-template-to-3-0)
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E13QMWgvwlA

It will help you to migrate the older template to newer version.