# coverting my joomla 2.5 template to 3.x

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Hopefully, this is the right place to ask this quesiton :o

I just upgrade from Joomla 2.58 to 3.51. Everything is going well I can use other templates
but I am having trouble with my template. I keep getting this error and
no matter how much I research and try I can't seem to get my template to work.

I have work through several errors but now I am stuck with this.

I am posting all the errors and the changes I made just in case it is related.

All Error

Deprecated: Non-static method JApplicationSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/templates/theme1308/index.php on line 26

fixed it by changing it to: $menus = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();

Deprecated: Non-static method JApplicationCms::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 272

this went away on its own

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/templates/theme1308/index.php on line 26

Went away on its own

Deprecated: Non-static method JApplicationSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/templates/theme1308/index.php on line 35

Fixed by changing it to: $menus = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();

Deprecated: Non-static method JApplicationCms::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 272

this went away on its own

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/templates/theme1308/index.php on line 35

this went away on its own

Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found in /home/cnkpadob/public_html/templates/theme1308/index.php on line 41

Still having this issue and can't figure it out. Tried to change it to $jparams = new JRegistry(); but it did not work.

Can anyone please help me with this.. it would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

By the way the stock templats works just fine and does not give me this error. So the problemis with my template.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please take a look at this tutorial, it will help you to fix these types of issues:[Link](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Converting_A_Previous_Joomla!_Version_Template)

Seams this types of question is already has answer in this forum,Look at [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055707/convert-joomla-2-5-template-to-3-0)